# Pros and cons of teaching as a PhD student for non-academic future

Tags: phd, teaching, industry

I started teaching this year. Since at the beginning the idea was just to do exercise sessions and now it starts becoming very (maybe too) time consuming with slide preparation, correction of homeworks and exams, I'm considering the idea to quit teaching.

My impression is that the time spent teaching/correcting/preparing is affecting very negatively the amount of time I spend in the research and the quality of my work.

Since from an economic point of view there are not a lot of advantages (roughly +10%), in the principle my idea was to earn teaching hours for a possible future in the academia, even without being sure about my future.

Since I have no idea about what to do after the phd and one of the possibilities is *industy* I was wondering whether ≈ 200 hours of teaching are seen positively from an industry perspective or if they are totally unnecessary from who is planning a future in the industry.

Comment: Quickly: learning how to deal with accidentally uncooperative co-workers/clients/subordinates, doing justice to everyone without going crazily over-time, setting up boundaries, and all that sort of professional-social stuff is very useful in all human endeavors (even maybe with hermits, who have to convince people to bring them scraps?) :)

Comment: The first time you teach a course there's a lot of overhead.  If you hold onto all your stuff, it gets more streamlined in subsquent semesters. // In some industry jobs, having teaching experience is helpful, to get the job and to be successful in it.  However, for some industry jobs, it wouldn't be very relevant. I think you could benefit from some career exploration -- by this I mean that you shadow one or two people working in your area, in industry.  You follow the person around for a half day or a whole day, getting a feel for the activities, getting to know the environment.

Comment: Not that your question is off topic, but it might get better answers at Workplace.  However, I do believe many companies value employees who can effectively teach things to others.

Comment: You (hopefully) learn how to communicate and present things in a clear and time-effective manner, how to plan not just for yourself but for others, and to spot and correct mistakes (I don't mean homework mistakes, but if the class as a whole is headed down one track and you figure out how to change the curriculum to be more effective). These are all essentially leadership skills.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the comments on your question already give a quite clear answer: Yes! Most industries *really* like someone that can communicate complex concepts clearly, either to management or to their team. Teaching a course is one of the best ways to learn this.

Personal note: I once had an interview for a relevant, part-time job, next to my Master's. The job I had at the time was as a rowing instructor, with poeple having very different skill levels and ranging in age from 20 to 80. Throughout the interview, we kept coming back to things I learned there, regarding communication, conflict solving, keeping a team together, that kind of stuff. Teaching a class will give you a similar experience in my opinion and will be a very valuable skill for any employer.

Comment: And don't discount all that experience standing in front of people and talking while thinking on your feet and answering questions. Perfect training for a real world job.